# Google AdMob Swift: Are ads always shown when called?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, admob

I´m new to Google AdMob with Swift (SwiftUI). I have a button titled "Watch ad" in my app settings and I'd like to present an ad every time when the button is tapped. Now to my question: Does every tap on the button reliably present an ad? Or can it also happen that Google says "No, now you won't get an ad"? I am very happy about help. Greetings

Comment: There are many reasons why there would be no ads to show. You have to account for that when you present ads.

Answer (score 0):

> Or can it also happen that Google says "No, now you won't get an ad"?

I don't know of any ad network that guarantees 100% fill. You should always be prepared to not get an ad at any time. You can use house ads, i.e. default ads that run free of charge in your own inventory, to fill the space if no paying demand is available. Even then, though, your app should be able to handle a no fill situation.

In other words, **yes,** it's entirely possible that AdMob won't give you an ad when asked.